# iOS data filtering error

Tags: ios, json, swift2

I have some code below. I have a JSON object from SwiftyJSON and I would like to filter that.
So naturally, I thought: let's filter it and instantiate a new array with the filtered data.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class SchoolSelectViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {
  let url = "https://mijn.magister.net/api/schools?filter=%%%".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
  var json: JSON = []
  var filteredJson: JSON = []
  var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, self.url!).validate().responseJSON {
      response in
      switch response.result {
      case .Success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
          self.json = JSON(value)
        }

        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        break
      case .Failure: break
      }
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Called tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath")
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("schoolSelectCell")! as UITableViewCell
    let cellTitle = json[indexPath.row]["Name"]
    let cellDetailTitle = json[indexPath.row]["Url"]

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle.string
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellDetailTitle.string

    return cell
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
      return self.filteredJson.count
    } else {
      return self.json.count
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = self.resultSearchController.searchBar.text
  }

  func filterContentForTextSearch(searchText: String) {
    self.filteredJson = self.json[0]["Name"].arrayValue.filter({
      (school: JSON) -> Bool in
    })
  }

}
```

But I end op receiving this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'JSON -> Bool' to expected argument type '(Element) -> Bool'`

How would I solve this?

Comment: What is `self.json`? Show its declaration so we know what type it is.

Comment: Edited question to give more information.

Comment: Did you find the reason? I wonder where it was.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter an array.

Use the following:

```
self.filteredJson = self.json.arrayValue.filter({
     (school: JSON) -> Bool in
      // Do something.
})
```

If the code above does not work, then check the type of `JSON`.

Comment: `Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (JSON) throws -> Bool)'`

Now receiving this error..

Comment: @jbehrens94, I just did quick testing with the following code:
        ```let json: JSON = ["a", "b", "c"]
        print(json.arrayValue.filter({ (letter: JSON) -> Bool in
            return letter.stringValue > "a"
        }))```

And it works, so I don't think that the issue is in syntax.

Comment: Nevertheless, the point is correct. `filter` applies to an array. A `JSON` object is not, of itself, an array — but it may be backed by an array. You need that array.

Comment: But how would I go about solving this then? I'm quite lost on how to tackle my bug right now.

Comment: I do not see `arrayValue` method in your code there.
And the most important part is empty.

Comment: It's empty, because how can I fill it with code when I can't build even the function declaration? And I edited the code, I accidentally picked an older version.

Comment: put 'return true' inside closure

Comment: Doesn't work, because the function declaration isn't right. It's not about the return value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95265/discussion-between-sviatoslav-yakymiv-and-jbehrens94).